# Javascript not working IE any version

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jcarousel

Hey everyone. I am having some issues on my end and hopefully it's just something on my end but, could someone take a look at **REMOVED SINCE FIXED** in IE and let me know if you can see what is wrong. Please check it out first in FF or Chrome or Safari because it all works fine in those browsers.

The two scripts I am using are a custom-ish dropdown menu and another using jcarousel lite. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: seems ok in IE8? what exactly is the issue?

Comment: can you check in IE7 as well? None of the scripts are firing on my machine all of a sudden. Maybe it's some issue with a setting somewhere, but I didn't change anything lately which is why it is baffling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in IE8 unless you turn on Compatibility View.

Then you get:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.4; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 04:24:30 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 41
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://www.fiftyonestudios.com/projects/web/bws/js/custom.js

And, no, the menus no longer work.

Comment: ahh yes. it was the comma... the extra comma threw it into a fit lol. amazing. thanks alot for the debugging.

Comment: looks like i have a z-index issue of some sort as well as the dropdown is falling behind the carousel in IE7 but only in IE7.

Comment: just for the record... this worked for the z-index issue: http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 1):

in IE7 i got error on line 41, you might want to remove extra comma in custom.js after speed : 600,

```
$(".bcinside").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    circular: false,
    visible: 6,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    speed: 600 
});
```

Comment: other than this was it working visually though? I think something got turned off somehow... I feel like I ran into this problem before and it was associated with a non-code related setting either on the system or within IE prefs.

Comment: not sure, i can't test it offline, you might want to install IE7 script debugger from microsoft. checkout this link for more info http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx